# TokenMismatchException on different workstations

Tags: php, forms, laravel, token, mismatch

**Laravel 5 Website**:

When my co-workers submit forms on the website, they are getting the error:

> tokenmismatchexception

My co-workers are both running on Mac-os and using Mamp to host the website.

I myself am running on *Windows 7 64bit* and using Xamp. I have never run into this error myself.

We all are using source-tree and they have the exact same project as me. Completely unedited. They've tried deleting and cloning it again but still the same problem.

This question is quite vague but I'd appreciate if someone could give some insight on what to look into for possible solutions.

Comment: is the _token hidden field being populated properly on the macs?, also, start using Vagrant, it is the best way to avoid these kinds of platform specific issues, I suspect something is awry with the crypto libraries on the macs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my live server.
For me the problem was that the sub-folders in storage/framework/ where not writable for everyone.
I had to set the chmod to 0777.
Be careful with this on live environments.